# App Engine Standard Python3 Handler Error Locally Only

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Running the dev server for App Engine standard python 3 is not routing requests properly.

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

The app.yaml file has 3 handlers.

```
runtime: python37
instance_class: F1

inbound_services:
  - warmup

handlers:
- url: /api/.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
- url: /
  static_files: public/index.html
  upload: public/index.html
  secure: always
- url: /
  static_dir: public
  secure: always
```

Locally the requests to /api/whatever all return 404 errors.
When I deploy the app to GCP the requests succeed.

The reasoning for my setup is statically hosting Angular 7 app while also hosting an API the angular app calls.

Since the issue is only associated with the dev server, I think this is a bug. There is a similar python 2 example here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/angular/app.yaml

Has anyone else run into this? Any workarounds?

**Update**: As requested in the comments here is an example main.py file.

```
# [START gae_python37_app]
import logging

from flask import request, url_for
from flask_api import FlaskAPI, status, exceptions

# Create flask app
app = FlaskAPI(__name__)

@app.route("/api/whatever", methods=["GET"])
def doSomething():

    response = {"message":"placeholder"}

    return response
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # This is used when running locally only. When deploying to Google App
    # Engine, a webserver process such as Gunicorn will serve the app.
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
# [END gae_python37_app]
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example by providing your main.py file? See here for more information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** I attempted to recreate the issue and there indeed seems to be a discrepancy between the dev_appserver.py and the deployed version. [I have created this issue on Google’s Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/139557399) to be properly followed up by the App Engine engineering team.

The answer below is only valid if your root directory doesn't contain a `static_dir` path

---

The issue is with the way that routing is implemented. I attempted to replicate the issue that you were having and I got the same results.

In my case, I was able to resolve it by changing the route from `/api/.*` to `('/api/<path:path>')`, since the function associated with that handle will then be properly defined as a catch-all [1](https://issuetracker.google.com/139557399).

Please refer to the code[2] provided along with the links provided[1](https://issuetracker.google.com/139557399).

[1](https://issuetracker.google.com/139557399) https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#routing

main.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
   """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
   return 'Hello World!'


@app.route('/api/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
   return 'Hello api page!'`


if __name__ == '__main__':
   # This is used when running locally only. When deploying to Google App
   # Engine, a webserver process such as Gunicorn will serve the app. This
   # can be configured by adding an entrypoint to app.yaml.
   app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)`
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python37

handlers:
- url: /
 script: auto

- url: /api/.*
 script: auto
```

Comment: Your solution does not work. From what I understand the culprit for the issue is the hadler:

- url: /
  static_directory: public
  secure: always